# Using Selenium and LeanFT together in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, selenium, leanft

I have seen that you can use Selenium and LeanFT together with Chrome and Firefox. Does anyone know how to do this using IE?

I am using C# in VS 2015

Comment: Repeated trial and error brought me to this solution:

Comment: var options = new InternetExplorerOptions { IgnoreZoomLevel = true }; _driverIE = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
 _browser = BrowserFactory.Attach(new BrowserDescription
            {
                Type = BrowserType.InternetExplorer,
                Title = "WebDriver"
            });
  _browser.Navigate(HomeUrl);
  _browser.Sync();

Answer (score 0):

```
        var options = new InternetExplorerOptions { IgnoreZoomLevel = true ;
        _driverIE = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);

        _browser = BrowserFactory.Attach(new BrowserDescription
        {
            Type = BrowserType.InternetExplorer,
            Title = "WebDriver"
        });
        _browser.Navigate(HomeUrl);
        _browser.Sync();
```